# Operating on values in different dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 separate dictionaries that I want to do operations on the data with. However, I only want to operate on data which has the same key in each dictionary. For example:

```
Dict_McDonalds= { 'Spain' : 500 , 'UK' : 100, 'JP': 50} 
Dict_BurgerKing={'Italy' : 30 , 'JP' : 50, 'Spain' : 1000}
```

If I want to calculate the average difference of locations both BK and McDonalds have in countries in which they both operate, how would I do that? I want to ignore countries that only one has operations in.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new dictionary with the distances. Iterate over the keys of one and check if it belongs to the other. Then calculate the difference.

```
Dict_McDonalds= { 'Spain' : 500 , 'UK' : 100, 'JP': 50} 
Dict_BurgerKing={'Italy' : 30 , 'JP' : 50, 'Spain' : 1000}
diff = {}

for i in Dict_McDonalds.keys():
    if i in Dict_BurgerKing.keys():
         diff[i] = abs(Dict_McDonalds[i] - Dict_BurgerKing[i])

print(diff)
```

There is also the option of using a dictionary comprehension:

```
Dict_McDonalds= { 'Spain' : 500 , 'UK' : 100, 'JP': 50} 
Dict_BurgerKing={'Italy' : 30 , 'JP' : 50, 'Spain' : 1000}

diff = {i:abs(Dict_McDonalds[i] - Dict_BurgerKing[i]) for i in Dict_McDonalds.keys() if i in Dict_BurgerKing.keys()}
print(diff)
```

```
output:
{'Spain': 500, 'JP': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact, that keys are unique in a dict and sets have intersection methods:

```
d_mc= { 'Spain' : 500 , 'UK' : 100, 'JP': 50} 
d_bk={'Italy' : 30 , 'JP' : 50, 'Spain' : 1000}

result = {}
for key in (set(d_mc.keys()) & set(d_bk.keys())):
    result[key] = d_mc[key] - d_bk[key]
```

Or (thanks to the other answer by Miguel as dict comprehension:

```
result = {key: (d_mc[key] - d_bk[key]) for key in (set(d_mc.keys()) & set(d_bk.keys()))}
```

Result:

```
{'Spain': -500, 'JP': 0}
```